# How to convert PyArrow table to Arrow table when interfacing between PyArrow in python and Arrow in C++

Tags: python, c++, pybind11, pyarrow, apache-arrow

I have a C++ library which is built against the Apache Arrow C++ libraries, with a binding to python using Pybind. I'd like to be able to write a function in C++ to take a table constructed with PyArrow, like:

```
void test(arrow::Table test);
```

Passing in a PyArrow table like:

```
tab = pa.Table.from_pandas(df)
mybinding.test(tab)
```

If I do a naive function as above, I get:

```
TypeError: arrow_test(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:
    1. (arg0: arrow::Table) -> None

Invoked with: pyarrow.Table
```

I've also tried to write a function that takes a `py::object` and `.cast<arrow::Table>()` but I can't do the casting:

```
RuntimeError: Unable to cast Python instance to C++ type (compile in debug mode for details)
```

Does anyone have any idea how to get this to work?

Comment: I think you need to unwrap the `pyarrow.Table`, see https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/extending.html#_CPPv412unwrap_tableP8PyObjectPNSt10shared_ptrI5TableEE

Comment: @Arthur this works, thanks! Its a bit annoying though since i'll need to link against pyarrow's library, rather than having something self contained in the cpp side.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the functionality provided in the `arrow/python/pyarrow.h` header. This header is auto-generated to support unwrapping the Cython `pyarrow.Table` objects to C++ `arrow::Table` instances. It is sufficient to build and link to `libarrow.so`. It will also require the `pyarrow` python packages loaded but this is solely a runtime, not a compile-time dependency.

```
// header that 
#include <arrow/python/pyarrow.h>

// Ensure that the Python module was loaded
arrow::py::import_pyarrow();

PyObject* pyarrow_table = …
// With pybind11 you can also use
// pybind11::object pyarrow_table = …

// Convert PyObject* to native C++ object
std::shared_ptr<Table> table = unwrap_pyarrow_table(pyarrow_table);
```

Comment: if ti do that on python/Cython side, how do you convert shared_ptr[CTable] returned by unwrap_pyarrow_table() into shared_ptr<arrow::Table>

Comment: `unwrap_pyarrow_table` is also available as a Cython function, you can simply use this. As  `pyarrow` also uses Cython, you can look into its source code for an example usage.

Comment: @UweL.Korn see https://github.com/finos/perspective/issues/1157#issuecomment-1656791171, this wont work in general due to C++ ABI incompatibilities, correct?